# Is this code exceptions handled correctly?

Tags: c++, exception, condition-variable, unique-lock

In the following code, it is possible that event throws exception and it may be not handled in even handler, (rare but its still the case)

I want keep "lck2" unlocked while executing the event, because I don't want main thread block for "mtx2", reason is nothing more than optimization.

Can I guarantee that "lck2" is always released in catch block? or there could be runtime exceptions and therefore it may cause deadlocks or some unexpected behavior?

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lck2(mtx2); // lock used for waiting for event.

while (_isRunning) 
{
    try
    {
        while (_isRunning)
        {
            // cvar2 is condition variable
            cvar2.wait(lck2, [&] {return invoke; }); // wait until invoke == true

            if (invoke) // if event must be invoked
            {
                lck2.unlock();
                OnEvent(this, someproperty); // may throw exception
                lck2.lock();

                invoke = false; // execution completed
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...) // we need to keep this thread alive at all costs!
    {            
        lck2.lock(); // is this safe?
        invoke = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `catch` block writes to `invoke` outside the mutex's protection

Comment: @WhiZTiM thanks for noting that, got it fixed

Comment: At the moment of catching the exception `lck2` is always unlocked.

Comment: Your `cvar2.wait(lck2, [&]{ return invoke; })` will only return if `invoke` is `true`. What is the purpose of testing `invoke` again?

Comment: I read something about Spurious wakeup, i didn't quite understand it but i thought adding if statement doesn't hurt too much. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup @WhiZTiM

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That's the entire purpose of the second overload of [`std::condition_variable.wait(lock, lambda)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait): to prevent execution proceeding without the condition being satisfied. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rewrite of your code would probably be more appropriate, to make it easier for another developer to work on the code. I will show you two rewrites:

- #### First, (Bad)

  ```
  while (true)
  {
      try
      {
          {
               std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lckx(mtx2);
               if(!_isRunning)
                     break;    //out of the main loop
          }

          bool should_invoke = false;
          {
                  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(mtx2);
                  cvar2.wait(lck2, [&] {return invoke; });
                  should_invoke = invoke;
          }     

          if (should_invoke) // if event must be invoked
          {
              OnEvent(this, someproperty); // may throw exception
              {
                  std::lock_guard<std:mutex> lckx(mtx2);
                  invoke = false; // execution completed
              }
          }
      }
      catch (...) // we need to keep this thread alive at all costs!
      {            
          std::lock_guard<std:mutex> lckx(mtx2);
          invoke = false;
      }
  }
  ```

---

- #### Second, (Good)

  Breaking the (first) code into smaller functional units; we also note that the expression `cvar2.wait(lck2, [&]{ return invoke; })` will suspend execution and only return if woken up **and** `invoke` is `true`, then we can infer that we only need that expression to wait. Hence we can discard the superfluous use of `invoke`. Hence we have:

  ```
  void do_work(){
      while(is_running()){
          try{
               wait_for_invocation();
               OnEvent(this, someproperty); // may throw exception
               set_invocation_state(false);
          catch(...){
               set_invocation_state(false);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Where the helpers are defined:

  ```
  bool is_running(){
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lckx(mtx2);
      return _isRunning;
  }

  void wait_for_invocation(){
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(mtx2);
      cvar2.wait(lck2, [&] {return invoke; });
  }

  void set_invocation_state(bool state){
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lckx(mtx2);
      invoke = state;
  }
  ```

Comment: in your second code after `cvar2.wait` in second helper method `lck2` is owned again. i want it to be unlocked when firing `OnEvent`

Comment: I guess i got it, `unique_lock` also works like `lock_gaurd` when its destructed right?

Comment: doesn't creating `unique_lock` at every iteration hurt performance or memory? assuming that events can be fired 100 times per second. (at rate of 0.01Hz)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, Yes... it releases the lock on destruction. See the documentation for [`std::unique_lock<T>::~unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/%7Eunique_lock). Well, as regards to performance, don't speculate until you have measured. :-)